# addActionLister parameter

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

I am getting expected output when i am using "**this**" reference in addActionListener() call, how can I achieve it using the object call directly ? When i am using jb.addActionListener(new EventHandling1());

I am getting error -"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException".

Also which object needs to be passed to this method addActionListener() ?

Below is the code which is failing with the above mentioned error.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class EventHandling1 implements ActionListener {

    JButton jb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventHandling1 eh = new EventHandling1();
        eh.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jb = new JButton("New button");
        jb.addActionListener(new EventHandling1());

        jf.getContentPane().add(jb);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(700, 500);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        jb.setText("Pressed!!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the NPE because the jb variable in your new EventHandling1 object is null since you never call `go()` on the **new object** (you do call it on the original, but that has no effect on the new one). Even if you get rid of the need to call `go()` say by folding all into the EventHandling1 constructor, you're still stuck up a tree, since the jb variable then will not refer to the same object as the displayed GUI.

I suggest that instead of creating a new EventHandling1 object, change EventHandling1 so that it does not implement ActionListener and then create a new ActionListener class, either an anonymous inner class, or else a private inner class, and instantiate that object in your parameter.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EventHandling1  {

    JButton jb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventHandling1 eh = new EventHandling1();
        eh.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jb = new JButton("New button");
        jb.addActionListener(new MyEventHandler());

        jf.getContentPane().add(jb);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(700, 500);
    }

    private class MyEventHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            jb.setText("Pressed!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Or if your listeners become more complex, then use a stand-alone outer class, or better still, a Control object. At times I have used a combination of anonymous inner classes and control objects like so:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (myControl != null) {
            myControl.myButtonAction(e);
        }
    }
});
```

---

You ask:

> in my code when I am using this reference, is it referring EventHandling1 object with reference jb ? >

When you use `this` as a parameter, you are using the current *displayed* object, one with a fully initialized JButton, jb. When you create and pass in a **new** EventHandling1 object, you are passing a distinct and new object (the key term being *new*), one that is not displayed, one without an initialized jb variable -- not good.

> Also, which all objects can be passed to addActionListener() ? in your code its taking MyEventHandler

You can pass in any object that implements the ActionListener interface.

Comment: in my code when I am using this reference, is it referring EventHandling1 object with reference jb ? Also, which all objects can be passed to addActionListener() ? in your code its taking MyEventHandler